# Woocommerce show products with and without prices on different shop pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My Woocommerce shop sell products to customers with prices shown, and has also has products with no prices, that are only ordered via the backend - me!

When you click on the ‘shop’ page in the menu it shows all products including the products with no prices.

What I want is a way to show on one 'shop' page products with prices.
Then on another 'shop' page products with out prices.

So its like having two 'shop' pages one with products with prices and another with products without prices. But separated.

Can this been done?
I don't want any complicated membership/user privileges plugin.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i would put them in categories. put the categories in your preferred menu, the one you want to show or both. and not show the main shop page in that menu. you not really hide your shop page but it is not in your menu anymore.